# $this->getQuote()->setData(); not working in saveBilling() in Onepage checkout Magento

Tags: php, attributes, magento-1.8

I am trying to set a custom attribute for customer in `saveBilling()` method of `Onepage.php`
Path for `Onepage.php` is

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
```

In `saveBilling()` i have written below code

```
$this->getQuote()->setData("customer_dri_license","22");
```

as you can see i am trying to set value `22` `for customer_dri_license`

I want to retrieve this value in `saveOrder()`, for that i have written below line of code

```
$this->getQuote()->getData("customer_dri_license")
```

but i am not receiving value '22' as set in `saveBilling()`

Please let me know if i'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Going to go ahead and assume you need to place your Quote into a variable and then manipulate it:

```
$quote = $this->getQuote();
$quote->setCustomerDriLicense('22');
$quote->save(); //save if you want to come back to it somewhere else later?
...
$dri_license = $quote->getCustomerDriLicense();
```